# Starting applications, `open` vs mouse click

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, beta

What is the fundamental difference, for `.app`-bundles/applications, between

> open Application.app

in a bash-shell and opening it by clicking on it in for example `Finder` or the dock?

It seems the environments are slightly different, at least in Mojave, which causes low-level differences in AppKit-resources. In this case I've encountered weird behaviour with NSView (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview).

Does anyone have information (developer level info) on what the differences are?

I Googled and went through Apple's developer info, but I couldn't find anything meaningful. Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What differences in behaviour? As far as I know they should be the same but the differences might suggest a place to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple developer info for 10.14 and AppKit had enough info to find the issue.

What mattered in this case was that the call order is slightly different depending on `open Application.app` or clicking on it. So do not assume call order for the first calls anymore.

The breaking change was that `resetCursorRects` (from `NSView` in AppKit) now can be called before the first redraw. AFAIK this was not the case previously.

See 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10_14?language=objc

Comment: Please put the reason in the answer - link only answers get problematic when the page changes - which Apple does do Also in this case that is a long document and it is not clear what is the relevant part